# What is an NSConcreteValue and how do I extract its value?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a library where I am receiving NSConcreteValue and I have no idea how to deal with it. I know the object I am supposed to get is a boolean, so how do i extricate the real value?

Comment: How do you know that you get NSConcreteValue? According to this link http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2003/Oct/msg00096.html that may be private subclass of NSValue class. Try to check that (as described in the link). Also try to log NSLog(@"%s", [yourConcreteValue objCType]) to see what exactly type is stored in that object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That’s a private class that’s sometimes (or all the times?) used behind the scenes when you work with `NSValue`. Or at least that’s my impression. I think you should be able to cast to `NSValue`:

```
// assuming value is of type “id”
NSAssert([value isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]],
    @"Sorry, I was wrong. Maybe try anyway?");
NSAssert(strcmp(@encode(BOOL), [value objCType]) == 0,
    @"The value does not seem to hold a BOOL.");
BOOL unwrappedValue;
[value getValue:&unwrappedValue];
```

…or something like that, I’m making this up :-)

Comment: +1 great examples of using NSAssert to verify class & value type. (although it's probably not necessary to do the cast to `NSValue` - just use `-getValue:`)

Comment: You’re right, I’m sure he’s not getting the value as `NSConcreteValue`. More likely he gets an `id` from a collection or something, I’ll edit the answer.

Comment: I - for one - am getting "something". When I log `[something class]` I get `NSConcreteValue` in the logs. That's why I would say that I am getting `NSConcreteValue`. Or how else should I check what this what I am getting actually is?